# "The base of this decision is on..." or "The basis of this decision is on..."?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I was reading an email and I came across the sentence

> The base of this decision is on the overall performance.

Is this correct?

Should it be the following?

> The basis of this decision is on the overall performance.

Comment: Please provide a full sentence for your example.

Comment: My apologies. "The base of this decision is on the overall performance."

Comment: No problem. Comments are considered ephemeral on this site - moderators sometimes delete them without notice. You’re better off using the [edit] link to update your question. (Insert the quote as if it was always in the question. The change-history is available for anyone who wishes to see what the original question looked like.)

Comment: Both versions seem ungrammatical to me. Better phrasing could be, "This decision was based on..." or "The basis for this decision was..."